# Set col in layout using boostrap for desktop & laptop 13inch

Tags: html, css

I have layout **limitless** for administrator. I want to set col in layout using boostrap for desktop & laptop 13inch.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-9"></div>
</div>
```

In laptop 13'inch is OK. But using monitor 1080 col-3 is too big. How can I set in monitor to col-2. Col-2 in monitor looks perfectly

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3"></div>
<div class="col-md-9"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I set in monitor col-2 & Col-3 on laptop bro